# Kendo Grid Scope Variable Null went Sent to Controller Unless Explicitly Set

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

This is the weirdest thing I have ever seen.  I am trying to post data collected from an Angular Directive to my MVC Controller in the Kendo Grid.
Here is the DataSource for the grid:

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/SSQV4/SSQV5/Search/SubmitCriteria",
                    data: { form: $scope.form }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Total"
            },
            pageSize: 25,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true

        }),
```

Here is the first line of the MVC Controller method:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitCriteria([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest command, ContractorSearchViewModel form)
```

The problem, although `$scope.form` has data it is null when it reaches the controller unless I explicitly set each value.  If I set:

```
$scope.form.UnitID = "558" in my Angular Controller, when it hits my MVC Controller the Value will be there.  However, if `$scope.form.UnitID` is set by user selection in the Directive, when my MVC Controller is hit, UnitID is null.
```

In an attempt to better explain the issue, although the value of the following:

```
var unitID = $scope.form.UnitID;
        $scope.form.UnitID = unitID;
```

is unitID = "558", the "558" only makes it to the MVC controller if I explictly set it like this:

```
$scope.form.UnitID = "558"
```

Does anyone know what I am missing here?  There is no way for me to manually set all the values as they are set when selected by the user in several pick lists.

I do know that it has something to do with the `$scope`, because if I "refresh" the page with "F5", all information is sent to the MVC Controller.  I tried using `$scope.$apply()` but I get the "digest already in progress" error.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!!!